# How do I make use of Real-time charting in TeeCharts

Tags: delphi, teechart

I want to use Fast line charting where I can make use of live / Real-time Data.

Where the points won't simply collect inside the Chart (Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Automatic := False;), but instead maintain the axis size, and either remove them from the display (or delete them entirely), but force the points to move from right-to-left.

I have looked over this page but can only find broken code for VCL. I would like to use up-to-date FMX.
http://www.teechart.net/reference/index.php

Just like the link above, many of the features or examples I have found from Standard or professional version of TeeCharts (Steema) consists of VCL code which is not compatible. What are the minor details that a Chart requires in order for continuous scrolling / shifting of Data Points

Comment: I tried doing this once, and gave up and drew my own real-time charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a real-time example showing how to add points from the right in the Features Demo program shipped with the binary installer,  at "All features\Welcome !\Speed\Fast Delete and Fast Pen"

[image]

In the "Source Code" tab you'll find VCL code, but it shouldn't be very different in FMX.

We'll check what can we do with those old articles.

Comment: I have tried this so far, like you mentioned (using the tool Tee9New_win64Delphi23.exe)  And once I started to use it, it began to make sense that that you were referring to an internal structure (All features/...), and not a file structure. I had to configure the program to let it know where the "features" actually were. "FastLine_Realtime.pas" is the source I'm modifying, I took out the TBaseForm and GDI, and started fresh, while still using the obj functions/TChart. There are data points in the chart, but it is not Repaint/Refreshing, and the axis is out of visual range.

Comment: I think its also good to note that the initial draw of the line graph is not showing a black line being drawn across the Y-axis, and its suppose to repaint and auto adjust the y-axis to show both lines. What I am getting is the lines are well above the visible portion, but when I pan (right-click mouse/drag) I do get to see the lines. But they only show any interaction when I move the mouse along the X-Axis, is where I see the series finally being "updated".

Comment: I Found it -- //Series1.AutoRepaint:=False; //Series2.AutoRepaint:=False;